# How to insert new parameter into column in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `device`, the table has a column called `devicMeta`. The `deviceMeta` looks like

```
{"id":"1234567890", "firmware":"1.001","hardware":"1.0"}
```

I want to insert a new parameter into column 'deviceMeta', for example `"company":'ABC'`, the expected result is

```
{"id":"1234567890","firmware":"1.001","hardware":"1.0","company":'ABC'}
```

How can I do this using PostgreSql's UPDATE command

```
UPDATE "device"
?
WHERE "id" = '1234567890'
```

Comment: What data type is `deviceMeta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be) you can simply [concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) the new key/value pair:

```
update device
  set devicemeta = devicemeta || '{"company": "ABC"}'
where id = 123456789;
```